# Where to find kerberos conf file in IIS server web application

Tags: windows, iis, kerberos, mit-kerberos

I have a web application in IIS server and it is enabled for kerberos.
I want to change few settings like rdns and dns_canonicalize_hosname but I am not aware where to do it.

I can do it in a linux server in krb5.conf file. I cannot find any krb5 file in windows server.

Please help me understand where I can find this file or if I have to create a fresh krb5.ini file. I am quite new to kerberos.

If the file has to be created, where should I place it so application in IIS server can use the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

It is only configurable in Linux or Java (with MIT kerberos implementation that is bundled with them). These settings are not configurable in windows.